# Getting the whole list of classes and objects defined in a unit using RTTI

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti

1. I want to get the whole list of classes defined in a specific unit
2. How can I get the list of all instances of those classes, irrespective of where they are created?

Comment: sorry for late response , i am using xe2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First before to answer your question, remember always include your delphi version in questions related to the Rtti.

1) Asumming which you are using a new version of delphi (>=2010) you can get the unit name of a type using the [`QualifiedName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/RTTI.TRttiType.QualifiedName) property , from there you must check the `IsInstance` property to determine if is a class.

Check the next sample.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Rtti,
  System.SysUtils;

procedure Test;
Var
 t : TRttiType;
  //extract the unit name from the  QualifiedName property
  function GetUnitName(lType: TRttiType): string;
  begin
    Result := StringReplace(lType.QualifiedName, '.' + lType.Name, '',[rfReplaceAll])
  end;

begin
 //list all the types of the System.SysUtils unit
  for t in TRttiContext.Create.GetTypes do
   if SameText('System.SysUtils',GetUnitName(t)) and (t.IsInstance) then
     Writeln(t.Name);
end;

begin
  try
    Test;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

2) The Rtti can't list the instances of the classes. because the Rtti is about type information and not of instances.

Comment: What about DeclaringUnitName? Is it Ok to use that?

Comment: Yeah this will work too, unfortunally the `DeclaringUnitName` is part of specific rtti types, but in this case for instances is ok. In the answer I recommend parse the `QualifiedName` to get the unit name because in the past I found some cases where the unit name is not present in some types check ths question for more info [Getting the Unit Name wich belongs to any type (TRttiType)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843628/getting-the-unit-name-wich-belongs-to-any-type-trttitype)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Oh, one more Q while I have your ear. Are `IsInstance` and `AsInstance` the idiomatic ways to do this as opposed to `is` or `as` operators?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `AsInstance` try to cast the type to `TRttiInstanceType` so will fail to types which not are instances (classes).

Comment: I read that other question now. It looks like the issue it refers to is when trying to find the unit name for any variety of `TRttiType`. But for an instance, and you are writing `IsInstance`, surely it's simpler and cleaner to use `DeclaringUnitName`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , yes is much more cleaner use `DeclaringUnitName`  and in this case works. In my answer I give a more general solution based on my experience because in the past I have issues resolving the unit name of some types.

Comment: OK, all clear now. I think that point would be better off in the answer than the comments. If you did that I'd be happy to delete all the comments and tidy up.

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1**

The following code does what you ask, relying on the new RTTI introduced in Delphi 2010:

```
program FindClassesDeclaredInUnit;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Rtti, MyTestUnit in 'MyTestUnit.pas';

procedure ListClassesDeclaredInNamedUnit(const UnitName: string);
var
  Context: TRttiContext;
  t: TRttiType;
  DeclaringUnitName: string;
begin
  Context := TRttiContext.Create;
  for t in Context.GetTypes do
    if t.IsInstance then
    begin
      DeclaringUnitName := t.AsInstance.DeclaringUnitName;
      if SameText(DeclaringUnitName, UnitName) then
        Writeln(t.ToString, ' ', DeclaringUnitName);
    end;
end;

begin
  ListClassesDeclaredInNamedUnit('MyTestUnit');
  Readln;
end.


unit MyTestUnit;

interface

type
  TClass1 = class
  end;

  TClass2 = class
  end;

implementation

procedure StopLinkerStrippingTheseClasses;
begin
  TClass1.Create.Free;
  TClass2.Create.Free;
end;

initialization
  StopLinkerStrippingTheseClasses;

end.
```

**Question 2**

There is no global registry of object instances.